# Touch Keyboard pops up on login on laptop

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1.1 and I can not get it to go away at login. I hit `Enter` and it will go away and if I lock my profile, it still pops up. How can I fix this?

> THIS IS **NOT** A DUPLICATE OF OTHER QUESTIONS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check startup programs in msconfig.

1. Go to the desktop.
2. Hold down the windows logo key and press the R key (Opens the run dialogue)
3. In the open box type in, msconfig then click on OK.
4. Click the "startup" tab.
5. Search the list until you find something that resembles On-Screen Keyboard.
   (I believe it to be osk.exe)
   6.Uncheck the box, apply.

Your next boot should be OSK free.